# Select date via selenium webdriver

Tags: java

I am unable select date or locate actual date using xpath or I want to select one date next to the current date at vipcars.com.
Here's a code I am using..

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {

         System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\chromedriver.exe");//any driver can be initialized like this just by replacing driver here.
         DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
         capabilities.setCapability("chrome", true);
         WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);

         driver.manage().window().maximize();

         // Test URL
         driver.get("https://www.vipcars.com/");

         driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
         String parent = driver.getWindowHandle();
         driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[id='supplycarsIframe']")));

         driver.findElement(By.id("pickup_country")).click();        
         Select country = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("pickup_country")));   
         country.selectByValue("441");


         driver.findElement(By.id("pickup_city")).click();       
         Select city = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("pickup_city")));     
         city.selectByValue("9747");

         driver.findElement(By.id("pickup_location")).click();       
         Select location = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("pickup_location")));     
         location.selectByValue("14927");

         driver.findElement(By.id("pickdate")).click(); //calender clicks   
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='From']")); //id found
         **driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='ui-datepicker-calendar']//tr[3]/td[6]"));** 



List<WebElement> allDates = (List<WebElement>) ((WebElement) driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='ui-datepicker-calendar']//tr[3]/td[6]"));
        (WebElement) allDates).click();
```

**Console error message :**

> java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement

Comment: Thanks for your reply lrnzcig..

Comment: Can you please suggest me the correct actual Xpath I should use to locate the calender element? I am not fond of using xpath so need suggestions on same.. I do need to locate for the current date or a date next to the current date. What should be the actual Xcode? (vipcars.com)

Comment: If you want to find the current date, then use `td[@class=' ui-datepicker-days-cell-over  ui-datepicker-today']`. In your xpath you get the 14th October and the 18th November, I think.

Comment: Thanks for your instant reply. Yes, I am looking for date 14th Oct. I am getting the same issue 'Unable to locate element' when Using your xcode

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@class=' ui-datepicker-days-cell-over ui-datepicker-today']")).click();

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is 
`(List<WebElement>) ((WebElement) driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='ui-datepicker-calendar']//tr[3]/td[6]"));`
You cast List to WebElement, which is not possible. After that you want to cast it to List, which is also not possible.

What do you expect and what do you want to do? Here are some examples to correct your code:

```
//this will return a List<WebElement> 
driver.findElements(Locator locator);

//this will return a WebElement
driver.findElement(Locator locator);

//if you know that there is only one element which you want to click, use this
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='ui-datepicker-calendar']//tr[3]/td[6]")).click();

//if there are more than one WebElements which can be found by that xpath locator, use this
List<WebElement> allDates = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='ui-datepicker-calendar']//tr[3]/td[6]"));
//now you can iterate through the list and do what you want, e.g. click every element
for (WebElement date : allDates) {
    date.click();
}
```

Comment: Hello @lrnzcig
Can you please check out the xpath I am using.